# Redirecionamentos para API's

Tags: nginx, apache

Boa tarde devs!

Meu problema é o seguinte: Tenho uma aplicação desktop em Delphi que utiliza alguns serviços em uma aplicação web. Precisei migrar a aplicação web para outro host e mudar o domínio também, então, criei um redirecionamento 301 pelo htaccess no host antigo apontando para o novo dominio no novo host. Tudo funciona acessando a interface via browser, porém, é retornado um erro 403 quando a aplicação client em Delphi tenta consumir os serviços.

Nota: A aplicação em Delphi continua direcionando os requests para o domínio antigo.

Nota2: Servidor antigo roda com Apache e o novo servidor roda com Nginx.

Existe alguma forma de contornar isto?

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o Delphi não está seguindo o redirecionamento.
Ele simplesmente pega um snapshot da página que vc passou e não continua com o redirecionamento.
Deve acontecer a mesma coisa quando tem algum ajax na página, e o Delphi não espera o ajax.

Infelizmente não consigo ajudar mais, espero ter clareado.

Comment: Provavelmente o problema é este mesmo. Eu li alguns materiais que orientam a criar um proxy reverso no servidor antigo (apache), mas não consegui fazer funcionar. O problema é que esta inviável atualizar todos os meus clientes que utilizam a ferramenta em Delphi.

Comment: e se vc colocar um frame na página?
ou então, se vc colocar um redirecionamento no onload em html, será que funciona?
se não quiser usar servidor, vc pode hospedar a página no github, pois apenas contem html e javascript.. segue tutorial https://woliveiras.com.br/posts/jamstack-criando-e-hospedando-seu-site-de-gra%C3%A7a-no-github-pages/